# 2 wordPress installs using 1 MySQL database

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress, hosting, multisite

I think this type of question has been asked before but I'm just wanting to get more concrete proof answers.

I'm currently based in Taiwan and looking at making some WordPress sites for people. My web host I'm looking at only allows 1 My SQL database and I'm wanting to install 2 WordPress installs on the 1 domain, not doing a multi-site setup just 2 separate installs through the Softaculous cPanel app (or similar apps like that). I will have both installs identical to one another except one website will be all in English for the foreign and the other I will put into Chinese language for the local visitors. The websites will range from single page to about 5 pages in total and won't include a blog.

I use OceanWP theme and Elementor.

I'm just wondering if its possible to do on 1 database without any issues being caused?

Thankyou.

Answer (score 1):

You can run both instances with a different [table_prefix](https://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#table_prefix). In this configuration you are relying on each wordpress instance to be well behaved and to look and modify at its own tables.